# MySQL Select same field name from two tables using UNION

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I'm trying to pull values from each table using the same query.  It's for an autocomplete box where the user could type in either a title or a genre.

I'd like to know whether a row is from the items_table or the item_genres_table.  The following isn't working.  It's returning all rows from both tables but the key for every row is item_title instead of some being item_genre as expected.

```
SELECT name as item_title FROM items_table 
WHERE name LIKE ? 
UNION
SELECT name as item_genre FROM item_genres_table
WHERE name LIKE ?
```

I have no control over database fields so I'm stuck with `name` in both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a union the names of the columns must match, if you want to know what table each field is coming from then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT name as item_name, 'item_table' as table_coming_from FROM items_table 
WHERE name LIKE ? 
UNION
SELECT name as item_name, 'item_genres_table' as table_coming_from FROM item_genres_table
WHERE name LIKE ?
```

This way you'll get an output like this:

```
name   |  table_coming_from
name1       item_table
name2       item_genres_table
....
```

Comment: Mostly right, but the names don't actually have to match; as the OP discovered, they are taken from the first SELECT in the UNION; the 2nd (& any further) queries can have no column names specified at all. What does have to match are the column types. Your solution, nonetheless, is spot on.